# Nginx SSL Breaks on Posted Forms

Tags: html, forms, nginx, ssl, https

All my GET based pages load fine, but posting forms returns a 400 response.

Here's my relevant Nginx config

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name tasks.technically.fun www.tasks.technically.fun;

    ssl_certificate ssl/technically.fun/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/technically.fun/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $Host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

The goal was to have all http endpoints get redirected to https, and then display a 400 error on unsupported domains.

The third server section *should* be covering all endpoints for `https://tasks.technically.fun/*`

When I inspect a form, say, the login form for my website, it looks like this:

[image: Posted Form Example]

Which you can see seems all correct.

I've isolated it to the `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";`, if I disable that my forms start working again.

However, this breaks my usage of SignalR, which relies on Websockets, and its my understanding I need that header for websockets.

Is best practice here to only do those three header modifications on a dedicated endpoint for where my SignalR endpoints sit?

Answer (score 0):

The solution had to do with the Websocket headers I was appending so that SignalR would work.

I don't know the details on why these headers broke my forms, but I modified my SignalR config to use a dedicated route and then seperated my `location` sections into two, one for normal routes, and a dedicated one for the websocket endpoint to use.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $Host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
location /taskHub {
    proxy_set_header Host $Host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

This lets my websockets continue to function on the /taskHub endpoint, but all other endpoints function as normal.

If anyone has details on why `Connection "upgrade"` header breaks form posting on SSL, that would be good to know and appreciated if you shared!